# I want to plot graph in polar coordinates not using ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

```
T = 1
S = NDSolve[{r''[t] == r[t] (θ'[t])^2, 
   m (2 r'[t] θ'[t] + r[t] θ''[t]) == T/r[t], 
   r[0] == 0.1, θ'[0] == 0,
   r'[0] == 0, θ[0] == 0}, {r, θ}, {t, 0, 100}]
```

> Now relation of `r[t]` and `θ` is parametric equation but I want to plot my graph in polar   by don't use ParametricPlot

Comment: `m`is undefined!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `m=1`

```
T = 1;
m=1;
S = NDSolve[{r''[t] == 
r[t] (\[Theta]'[t])^2,  (2 r'[t] \[Theta]'[t] + 
r[t] \[Theta]''[t]) == T/r[t], r[0] == 0.1, \[Theta]'[0] == 0, 
r'[0] == 0, \[Theta][0] == 0}, {r, \[Theta]}, {t, 0, 100}][[1]]
```

we have to solve `teta= \[Theta][t]` for t

```
solt = Solve[(\[Theta][t] /. S) == teta, t][[1]]
```

and substitude into result `r[t]`

```
PolarPlot[Evaluate[r[t] /. S /. solt], {teta, 0 , 3.39},AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-120, 0}, {-10, 5}}]
```

[image]

The advantage compared to `ParametricPlot` is not clear to me.